# Reverse-Engineering of a ATARI-ST-Program

Tags: reverse-engineering, 68000

I've got an old Atari-ST-program written in the 90s in Omikron Basic. I'd like to have a disassembler for Windows or Linux that disassembles the code with a graphical output for the calls and jumps. What I would appreciate even more would be a disassembler that outputs a pseudo-C-code.

Comment: Asking people to locate tools for you is off-topic here at StackOverflow. Try an Atari ST-related forum instead, or something like pouet.net.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of disasembler tools for Windows and Linux to do what you want to do. Do some search at Atari forum ... e.g. http://www.atari-forum.com/viewtopic.php?t=14540 ...